# Extending $\frac{x}{2}\coth (\frac{x}{2})$ in $0$

Tags: calculus

I read that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}\coth (\frac{x}{2})=\frac{x}{e^x -1}+\frac{x}{2}$ can be extendend, together with all its derivatives of any order, to a continuous function in $x=0$. I find it easy to check that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)= 1$ and that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh x-x}{4\sinh^2(x/2)}= 0$, but I can't find a general formula for the $n$-th order derivative, in order to check that it has got a finite limit in $0$, or any other mean to prove that we can build a function $\tilde{f}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, by defining it $\tilde{f}(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{x}{2}\coth (\frac{x}{2}), & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \\ 1, & x=0 \end{cases}$.

Has anybody any idea?
I $\infty$-ly thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g$ defined by $g(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$ for $x \ne 0$ and $g(0) = 1$  can be represented as a power series centred at $0$. This can be proved by starting with the usual power series representation for $e^x$, subtracting $1$, and then dividing by $x$.

Therefore $g$ is infinitely differentiable. Thus $f(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)} + \frac{x}{2}$ is also infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand that $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}$ has got derivatives of any order with finite limit in $0$, but I don't understand why $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ also has...

Answer (score 1):

In ${\Bbb C}$, $1/(e^z-1)$ has a simple pole in $z=0$ and the $z$ of the numerator kills the pole. There is a power series equal to $z/(e^z-1)$ for $z$ near 0, $z\ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Martín! How can we see that $\frac{1}{e^x -1}$ is developable as a Taylor series in a neigbourhood of $0$ and deduce that $\frac{x}{e^x -1}$ has got derivatives of any order with finite limit in $0$?

Comment: As in the other answer, the quotient of $C^\infty$ or analytic functions is $C^\infty$or analytic **if** you can divide (no zeros pooping the party).

Comment: I understand: if $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=1$ and $f(x)=1/g(x)+x/2$ then any $f^{(n)}(x)$ can be written with only powers of $g(x)\to 1$ at the denominator. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To add to a previous answer, $h(x) = 1/g(x)$ is the composite of $f(u) = 1/u$ and $g(x)$. It is easily proved by induction that if two functions $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable $n$ times, then so is $f \circ g$.